# Checked Radio Button always grey Android XML

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-studio, android-layout

I already set the radio button tint color and enabled it. But it still grey. Here is the code in xml :

```xml
<RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/rg_switch_mode"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ll_estimated_data">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rad_btn_detectObj"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Detect Object"
            android:buttonTint="@color/its_blue"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:checked="true"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rad_btn_imgCapt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Image Captioning"
            android:buttonTint="@color/its_blue"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:textSize="14sp"/>
    </RadioGroup>
```

And I set `<item name="colorControlActivated">@color/its_blue</item>` in themes.xml inside the app theme.

But still this is the preview [image: radiobutton grey]

Answer (score -1):

To change the color of a radio button in Android Studio, you should use a custom XML drawable for the button background
Create a new XML drawable resource file:

1. Right-click on the res/drawable folder in your Android Studio project and choose "New -> Drawable Resource File." Give it a name, such as custom_radio_button_background.xml.
2. Edit the XML drawable file:

Open the newly created XML file and add the following code to create a custom background with the desired color:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Checked state -->
    <item android:state_checked="true">
        <layer-list>
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="oval">
                    <solid android:color="@color/your_checked_color" />
                    <!-- Change the color to your desired checked color -->
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item android:drawable="@android:drawable/btn_radio" />
        </layer-list>
    </item>

    <!-- Unchecked state -->
    <item android:state_checked="false">
        <layer-list>
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="oval">
                    <solid android:color="@color/your_unchecked_color" />
                    <!-- Change the color to your desired unchecked color -->
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item android:drawable="@android:drawable/btn_radio" />
        </layer-list>
    </item>
</selector>
```

3. Apply the custom drawable to your radio button and use button attribute

> android:button="@drawable/custom_radio_button_background"

```
<RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/rg_switch_mode"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ll_estimated_data">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rad_btn_detectObj"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Detect Object"
            android:button="@drawable/custom_radio_button_background"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:checked="true"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rad_btn_imgCapt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Image Captioning"
            android:button="@drawable/custom_radio_button_background"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:textSize="14sp"/>
    </RadioGroup>
```

Comment: Welcome (back) to Stack Overflow! Please note that use of AI Tools (e.g., ChatGPT) to generate or reword content that you post [is not permitted](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831) on Stack Overflow, even if you vet this content beforehand. Also see the related [Help](/help/ai-policy) on this topic. We do hope you'll stick around and continue to be a valuable member of the community by contributing your own quality answers and questions in the future!